# Passing Argument with Application.Run in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following two Sub defined in my Word Addin (.dotm) which I have put in StartUp directory

```
Public Sub SayHi1()
    MsgBox "Hi......."
End Sub

Public Sub SayHi2(ByVal n As String)
    MsgBox "Hi " & n
End Sub
```

Then from a new document I am able to call 1st Sub without argument as below:

```
Sub AppRun_AddIn_NoArg()
    Application.Run "MyProject.Module1.SayHi1"
End Sub
```

But when I try to run the 2nd Sub with argument I get error saying "Object doesn't support this property or method"

```
Sub AppRun_AddIn_WithArg()
    Application.Run "MyProject.Module1.SayHi2", "Tejas"
End Sub
```

Error Message:
[image]

Comment: For some reason it works if you remove the `MyProject` bit - but then obvously you might end up calling the wrong macro. Apparently this has something to do with ["If you specify the document name, your code can only run macros in documents related to the current context — not just any macro in any document"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838935.aspx).

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using Call?

Comment: @GSerg Yeah, Without project name & module name it worked.

Comment: @jbarker2160: no specific reason. Is there any advantage I will get by using Call ?

Comment: @Tejas There is - you'd be able to call it using the fully qualified name, and you'll get intellisense. And it will be slightly faster to work. You use `.Run` when the macro name is not known at compile time, if you do know it at compile time, just call it directly.

Comment: @GSerg When i write call, I dont get my function or project name in intellisense. My function is in another file, so call won't work I think. Can you show an example?

Comment: In the code editor, go to Tools - References, click Browse, select "Word Documents" from the File Type dropdown, navigate to the template and select it. This creates a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be long-standing problem with Word.

As [KB190235 suggests](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/190235):

> **Cause:**
> You have included a template name as part of the Macroname argument string.
>
> **Resolution:**
> Remove the template name from the Macroname argument.
>
> **Workaround:**
> To avoid naming conflicts among referenced projects, give your procedures unique names, so that you can call a procedure without specifying a project or module.