# Embed VBA macro in VSTO Add-in

Tags: vba, vsto, ms-word

I have a `VSTO Add-in` for `Microsoft Word` and I wish to embed a macro so it will be globally available from all VBA projects or other VSTO add-ins.

Is that possible? If so, how can it be done?

I hope it can be done without requiring `Trust access to the VBA project object model` ([info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-disable-macros-in-Office-documents-7b4fdd2e-174f-47e2-9611-9efe4f860b12)) since I don't like having to ask my customers to do that.

I know that macros can be executed from VSTO [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735815/how-to-run-existing-word-vba-macros-from-c-sharp-ribbon-addin)

> You define a function `RunMacro`
>
> ```
> private void RunMacro(object oApp, object[] oRunArgs)
> {
>     oApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run",
>         System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default |
>         System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
>         null, oApp, oRunArgs);
> }
> ```
>
> and then call your macro like this:
>
> ```
> RunMacro(oApp, new object[] {"NameOfMyMacro"})
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> RunMacro(oApp, new object[] {"NameOfMyMacro", "some", 3, "parameters"})
> ```
>
> `oApp` is the `Word.Application` object, which I'm sure is available somewhere in a Word add-in.

It's also possible to execute the macro from VBA [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063986/passing-argument-with-application-run-in-word-vba)
(Paraphrased)

> ```
> Sub AppRun_AddIn_NoArg()
>     Application.Run "ModuleName.MethodName1"
> End Sub
> ```
>
> And with arguments:
>
> ```
> Sub AppRun_AddIn_WithArg()
>     Application.Run "ModuleName.MethodName2", "ArgumentValue"
> End Sub
> ```

The "embedded" macros I ask about here, should be executable in the same manner, for maximum compatibility with third parties.

Comment: I am sure there is a good reason, but I must ask. Why not just add the macro you intend to call into the VSTO add-in itself?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but it sounds like what I'm trying to do. "host" a macro in the VSTO add-in, so it can be executed from VBA or other VSTO add-ins as if it was "hosted" in a document.

Comment: You can insert the macro as a string, then run it?

Comment: How would you do that in practice?